# Navigate Wpf Page to Ribbon Application

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, ribbon

I am trying to navigate Page to Ribbon Window and I'm getting this error:

> 'WpfRibbonApplication1.MainWindow' root element is not valid for navigation'

My navigation code in Page is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
    nav.Navigate(new System.Uri("MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

Anyone help?

Comment: I found answer to my question. 

(this.Parent as Window).Close(); solved my problem. Pages cant close themself. So need to tell  page's host window to close.